# Why \nointerlineskip if background of Beamer-color frametitle is empty?

Tags: beamer, color, source

I'm trying to read the source of Beamer default outer theme (the file `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`).  In line 144 there is this code:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{default}[1][left]
{
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  % more things here
}
```

My question is simple: what is the purpose of this `\nointerlineskip`, and how is this connected to the background of the `frametitle` Beamer-color?

Edit: I checked on the repository on Bitbucket, and couldn't find any hints there (I hoped for some enlightening commit message found through "blame" - but no, nothing.)

Comment: `\nointerlineskip` is useful, for example, when one wants to place two boxes (in vertical mode) one exactly above the other, with no glue between them.

Comment: @egreg: I know that, but the frametitle seems to be at the very top of the page anyway.  After asking the question, I gave it a little thinking, and I have two hypotheses: (1) maybe `\nointerlineskip` suppresses `\topskip`? (I don't think so.) (2) maybe `beamercolorbox` puts some kind of a box *above* its contents (probably yes, though it'll take some time for me to analyse its code).

Comment: After skimming through beamer sources, it seems that hypothesis (2) is *very* probable.  If nobody wants to answer this question, I'll probably be able to answer it myself in some time;)...

Comment: @mbork Care to answer here? (Till left us basically no notes on lots of odd things in `beamer`, and that makes my life 'interesting' whenever I try to fix something.)

Comment: @mbork Please take a look at this and add an answer if you've got one

Comment: @mbork care for an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the definition of `beamer@frameslide` environment in `beamerbaseframe.sty`, there is an empty `vbox` above the `frametitle`:

```
\ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
  \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\box\voidb@x%
\else%
  \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\vbox{
    \vbox{}%
    {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}\vskip0.25em}%
  }%
\fi%
```

Now assume we remove `\nointerlineskip` line from the template code for `frametitle`, then there will be vertical space between the empty `vbox` and `frametitle`:

```
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
.\hbox(19.136+0.0)x324.79259
```

The vertical space comes from `\lineskip`, since by default the height of the `frametitle` box is larger than `\baselineskip`.

When the backgoround color of the `frametitle` is empty, this extra vertical space is usually unobtrusive. But if the background color exists, and furthermore if the headline also exists, this space looks redundant：

[image][image]

To get rid of this extra space, we may also patch `beamer@frameslide`, removing the extra `vbox{}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Default frame title}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
% remove \nointerlineskip in frametitle template
\xpatchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle}{\nointerlineskip}{\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title without nointerlineskip}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
% undo the above patch
%\xpatchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@frametitle}{\relax}{\nointerlineskip}{}{}
% patch in another way: modify beamer@frameslide environment
\xpatchcmd{\endbeamer@frameslide}{\vbox{}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title without empty vbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```